# pH at different concentrations

Tags: ph, concentration

In making gummies with pectin, the pH is very important and needs to be at or below 3.4.  USP indicates dissolving it in a 10% solution to test the pH, while some use a 50% solution.  I'm told the resulting pH is the same, but my rudimentary understanding of pH is that pH is the hydrogen ion *concentration* in solution.  Why would the pH be the same if the concentration of gummy to water is different?